# Asynchronous loading of select list options

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, html-select

I'm retrieving information on Municipality names, ZipCodes, etc. from a public service provider (DAWA) using AJAX. At first I had an issue retriving the data until I made the transfer asyncronous, thus `ajaxGetMunicipalitiesFromDAWA` is an asyncronous function. I have checked `ajaxGetMunicipalitiesFromDAWA` and it loads data correctly.

The I try to update my selectlist using the data, but it seems the update occurs before Municipalies is loaded. I have tried to make `loadMunicipalities` asyncronous as well, but still I end up having an empty option list.

Please help

HTML code:

```
<div class="row mt-3 fw-bold">
    <div class="col-3"><label asp-for="PostalAddress_Municipality">Municipality:</label></div>
    <div class="col-9">
        <select asp-for="PostalAddress_MunicipalityId" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="municipality"></select>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
    var Municipalities = ajaxGetMunicipalitiesFromDAWA();
    
async function ajaxGetMunicipalitiesFromDAWA() {
    var output = [];
    var xHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            var dawaData = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            dawaData.forEach(function (data) {
                output.push({ Id: data.kode, Name: data.navn, CountryId: 53, CountryText: "Danmark", RegionId: data.regionskode, RegionText: data.region.navn });
            });
        }
    }
    xHttp.open("GET", "https://dawa.aws.dk/kommuner", true);
    await xHttp.send();
    return output;
}

async function loadMunicipalities() {
    var select = document.querySelector("municipality");
    var data = await Municipalities;
    data.forEach(function (municipality) {
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value = municipality.Id;
        option.text = municipality.Name;
        option.selected = select.value == municipality.Id;
        select.add(option);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things, [XMLHttpResquest.send](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send) does not return a promise. So awaiting `send` will just await for the an empty microtask to complete and not actually the request. What you'd want to do is just wrap the request in a `Promise` which will be handled by the async FSM. You also need to actually call `loadMunicipalities` so that the list is actually populated. Below is a working example.

```js
var Municipalities = ajaxGetMunicipalitiesFromDAWA();

async function ajaxGetMunicipalitiesFromDAWA() {
  var output = [];
  var xHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    xHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var dawaData = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

        dawaData.forEach(function(data) {
          output.push({
            Id: data.kode,
            Name: data.navn,
            CountryId: 53,
            CountryText: "Danmark",
            RegionId: data.regionskode,
            RegionText: data.region.navn
          });
        });

        resolve(output);
      }
    }
    xHttp.open("GET", "https://dawa.aws.dk/kommuner", true);
    xHttp.send();
  });

}

async function loadMunicipalities() {
  var select = document.querySelector("#municipality");
  var data = await Municipalities;

  data.forEach(function(municipality) {
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = municipality.Id;
    option.text = municipality.Name;
    option.selected = select.value == municipality.Id;
    select.add(option);
  });
}

loadMunicipalities();
```

```html
<select id="municipality"></select>
```

So this works as is, but since you are using semi modern apis, id recommend that you use [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch) as it handles almost all the fixes applied but makes the code much less verbose.

```js
const requestMunicipalitiesFromDAWA = async() => {
  const response = await fetch("https://dawa.aws.dk/kommuner");
  const data = await response.json();
  
  return data.map((datum) => ({
    Id: datum.kode,
    Name: datum.navn,
    CountryId: 53,
    CountryText: "Danmark",
    RegionId: datum.regionskode,
    RegionText: datum.region.navn
  }));
};

const populateMunicipalitiesOptions = (data) => {
  var select = document.querySelector("#municipality");
 
  data.forEach(function(municipality) {
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = municipality.Id;
    option.text = municipality.Name;
    option.selected = select.value == municipality.Id;
    select.add(option);
  });
};

requestMunicipalitiesFromDAWA().then(populateMunicipalitiesOptions);
```

```html
<select id="municipality"></select>
```

Comment: Thx. I have been working a lot in C# lately and completely forgot about Promises in javascript.